# convert csv with bash tools _0

Tags: bash

have a `valvu.csv` this have this in "Column A" https://pastebin.com/0FCgHiy4

I can read it but I do not know how to continue.

```
#!/bin/bash
one=2000
two=3000
high=10

while IFS=, read -r col1
do
echo "$col1"
done < values.csv
```

i with sed `'s/,/ /g'` can i split from `2750,2.2941` to `2750 2.2941`

now my question. I search the largest number between $one and $tow from the first row (example 2750  with the highest number from the second row ( exampl 2.2941)

the result would be at `valvu.csv` 2290 18.4881.

I would like to write this in a CSV in the same line wo in column A the filename is  "name from csv", column B 2290, column A 18.4881

Big thx for help
Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is always recommended to post your samples in text format in CODE TAGS so please do so and let us know then.

Comment: Hello, RavindeSingh13, the export is only in .csv, i dont can from another programm export in text fromat.

Answer (score 0):

As Guys here already mentioned is always good to post test case/sample output.

Anyway If I get Your question You need to find maximum value from 2nd column considering range of first column between `$one` and `$two` variables and print it out with 1st column value in space separated format. Then You can use following AWK:

```
awk -F',' '($1>'${one}')&&($1<'${two}') {if ($2>max) {max=$2; x=$1;}} END {print(x " " max);}'
```

Test:

```
$ one=2000
$ two=3000
$ awk -F',' '($1>'${one}')&&($1<'${two}') {if ($2>max) {max=$2; x=$1;}} END {print(x " " max);}' valvu.csv > output
$ cat output
2290 18.4881
```

Comment: wow nice Kubator, when i test its output 2280 8.4768 and not 2290 18.4881